# Can you hard code an Azure AD login into an application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, powerbi, adal, azure-active-directory

I'm designing an application that uses embedded Power BI reports that requires an authentication token from an Azure AD account to view the report.

On navigating to the page that holds the report, the user is directed to a Azure AD portal login, and once they enter their credentials they are redirected back to the correct page with a url that contains the access token. The token is then pulled from the url and used in displaying the report.

So my question is (seemingly) simple: Can I skip the navigating to another page and somehow hard code an Azure login into my app?

I'm not sure if this requires any of my code, as it's more of an abstract/general question.

But here is the redirect to the Azure AD login portal:

```
 Response.Redirect(String.Format("https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?{0}", queryString));
```

And here I fetch the code from the resulting URL after the user authenticates:

```
model.code = Request.Params.GetValues("code")[0];
```

Comment: Are the reports/data specific to the logged in user?  If they are not specific to the user then I would recommend looking at "Power Bi Embedded" service https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/power-bi-embedded/  With power bi embedded you do not need to use the users credentials you are given an access key.

Comment: You can use ADAL with UserCredential to get access token with username and password

Comment: @JustLogic yes, the reports are user specific.

Comment: @CuongLe ADAL UserCredential is limited to native applications, not web apps, correct? This application is running as a web app, sorry I guess I didn't make that clear.

Comment: @j76: no limitation like that, the purpose is to get the access token silently, UserCredential is the best approach. I was on your situation before to embed Power BI Service to our web application

Comment: @CuongLe I have tried that, but I am getting errors. What method do you call to get your token? Would you mind providing a bit of code?

Comment: ` authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUrl, ClientId, userCredential);`

Comment: Also make sure you have the latest version of ADAL or that overload might not exist.

Comment: Yes, should be ADAL 3

Comment: So I updated ADAL to 3.12, and I am trying to run the AcquireTokenAsync method, but in updating ADAL, it seems UserCredential no longer accepts usernames and passwords? The only constructor available for it contains a username. [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.usercredential.aspx) here shows it should accept two strings, but it is not letting me. When I try to call the method to acquire token, I'm getting an error `password_required_for_managed_user: Password is required for managed user`

Comment: So ignore my last comment, I fixed it by changing my UserCredential to
`UserCredential uc = new UserPasswordCredential(usr, pwd);`
But now I'm getting a 400 (bad request) error when I try to call the method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. AAD supports headless auth. Please see the example here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless.